# Session is not being set on redirect request

Tags: php

Problem is: session is not being set another time after the page is redirected.
Have a look at my code:

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$pg=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$pg=substr($pg,0,11);
$_SESSION['pg']=$pg;
?>
<form action='test.php'>
...
...
</form>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$pg=$_SESSION['pg'];
if(some_condition){
    echo "<script>";
    echo "window.location='".$pg."'";
    echo "</script>";
}
?>
```

First time, it works fine, it redirects to login.php. After first redirect (test.php to login.php), session is not being set again & so no redirect then after.

Can anyone tell why session is not being set after redirect?

Comment: do you have session_start() at the beginning of both files ?

Comment: Yes, forgot to add it

Comment: try replacing in login.php : $pg = ((isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) ? $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] : '');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow it still removes a session, can't still get the reason. Tried with setting up a cookie & made it consistent with pages needed.

```
if($_COOKIE['loginpage']!='/test.php'){
    $pg=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $pg=substr($pg,0,9);
    setcookie('loginpage',$pg,false,'/');
}
```

As cookie is persistent across all two/three pages, it works fine.
Thank you all for your help, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `substr` in the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns **/url.php**, not **http://server.com/url.php**, so redo your `substr` function and it should work.

Comment: That doesn't seem the issue & it didn't work too. I've been using window.location for many pages with substr function only as I need absolute URL only, like `url.php` & not `url.php?message=Test`